# sed: remove from regex

Tags: sed

I want to remove each line from the first time a number appears, including the last whitespace that appears before the number.

For example:

```
'foo 100 300' -> 'foo'
'fOo Bar 222x asdf 888' -> 'fOo Bar'
```

I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/([a-zA-Z ]*)( [0-9]+)/$1/g' input.file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you can use this command:

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*[0-9].*$//g' <file>
```

Comment: The `g` in the end is not needed.